# Change Color of Bottom Tab React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm very new to `React Native`. I started a project using `Expo` and used the `Tabs` template. I want to change the off focus (when not selected) color of the tabs. How can I do this? Here is a tab:

```
<BottomTab.Screen
        name="Settings"
        component={TabFourNavigator}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <TabBarIcon name="cog" color={color} />,
        }}
      />
```

I don't know what the color variable is and don't know how to change it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it.. I think you want this:

```
<Tab.Navigator
  initialRouteName="Feed"
  tabBarOptions={{
    activeTintColor: 'orange',
    inactiveTintColor: 'red',
  }}
>
```

activeTintColor and inactiveTintColor on the snack example I played with this colors and did what I wanted

Answer (score 2):

Expo uses React Navigation as their routing library. You can see that in the Expo docs [here](https://docs.expo.io/guides/routing-and-navigation/).

Learning about styling the Tabs will probably be easier from the React Navigation docs directly. You can read about "tabBarOptions" [in this part of the docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#tabbaroptions).

Now going back to your button, I believe you should add [activetintcolor](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#activetintcolor)

```
<BottomTab.Screen
  name="Settings"
  component={TabFourNavigator}
  activetintcolor="#bada55"
  options={{
    tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <TabBarIcon name="cog" color={color} />,
  }}
/>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be working. Maybe it is getting overriden by this: `const colorScheme = useColorScheme();`?? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
<BottomTab.Screen
        style="backgroundColor: "#color""
        name="Settings"
        component={TabFourNavigator}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <TabBarIcon name="cog" color={color} />,
        }}
      />
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work. But also, I dont want to change the backgorund color, just the color of the text and the icon.